# Log of all applications that run or running manually on PC with start/end time

Tags: windows

I'm wondering if there's any log which stores information about a particular program such as when the program has started and closed manually on Windows such as MS Word, or Chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: check the newest Sysinternals tool called SysMon: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dn798348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mark Russinovich* and *Thomas Garnier* released a tool called [SysMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dn798348) which allows logging of started processes:

*Sysmon includes the following capabilities:*

- Logs process creation with full command line for both current and parent processes.

Analyze the log details in Eventviewer:

[image]

*//Edit*

Since End of May 2017, we see a lot of questions about a small command windows popping up. This is caused by `OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerRegistration` scheduled task.

Disable this task in task scheduler under ask Scheduler -> Microsoft -> Office ->

[image]